# Validate CCK field to not allow links/URLs

Tags: forms

I want to allow users to input free text, but don't want them including any links or references to URLs. I know how to set up a filter on the CCK field so that 'a' tags cannot be included, but this will not stop the user typing www.google.com etc.

I have tried searching for modules to achieve this, but have not managed to find any. Does anyone know of a module to filter CCK fields to validate for 'www', '.com' etc, or alternatively one for custom CCK validation?

If there aren't any modules I think I would have to follow these [instructions to build a custom CCK Validation module](http://www.webscaped.com/articles/2009/03/custom-field-validation-in-drupal/). I would appreciate advice on whether this would be the most efficient approach or if this would be reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Update: I have just found that there is a validate link on the CCK manage fields page that allows you to add validation rules the 'Regular expression (POSIX multibyte)' looks promising. Now I just need to figure out how to write the correct regular expression to fail validation if 'www' etc is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I have worked out how to do this.

First install the [Field validation module](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation).

Then go to the 'manage fields' page for your content type. To the right of each field is a 'validate' link. Click on validate for the field you wish to add validation for.

Click 'PHP code' and note the 'Be careful, it is powerful and also dangerous.' warning!

Enter a rule name such as 'dont allow URLs'.

In the PHP code box enter the php you wish to validate. I made an array of all the the top level domains etc I didn't want users to use, and checked the input against this in a foreach loop. The code I used to do this is:

```
$mystring = $this->value;
$arr = array("http", "https", "www", ".com", ".org", ".net", ".info", ".mil", ".mobi", ".edu", ".gov",  ".biz", ".ac", ".ad", ".ae", ".af", ".ai", ".al", ".am", ".ao", ".aq", ".ar", ".as", ".at", ".au", ".aw", ".ax", ".az", ".ba", ".bb", ".bd", ".be", ".bf", ".bg", ".bh", ".bi", ".bj", ".bm", ".bn", ".bo", ".br", ".bs", ".bt", ".bw", ".by", ".bz", ".ca", ".cc", ".cd", ".cf", ".cg", ".ch", ".ci", ".ck", ".cl", ".cm", ".cn", ".co", ".cr", ".cu", ".cv", ".cw", ".cx", ".cy", ".cz", ".de", ".dj", ".dk", ".dm", ".do", ".dz", ".ec", ".ee", ".eg", ".er", ".es", ".et", ".eu", ".fi", ".fj", ".fk", ".fm", ".fo", ".fr", ".ga", ".gd", ".ge", ".gf", ".gg", ".gh", ".gi", ".gl", ".gm", ".gn", ".gp", ".gq", ".gr", ".gs", ".gt", ".gu", ".gw", ".gy", ".hk", ".hm", ".hn", ".hr", ".ht", ".hu", ".id", ".ie", ".il", ".im", ".in", ".io", ".iq", ".ir", ".is", ".it", ".je", ".jm", ".jo", ".jp", ".ke", ".kg", ".kh", ".ki", ".km", ".kn", ".kp", ".kr", ".kw", ".ky", ".kz", ".la", ".lb", ".lc", ".li", ".lk", ".lr", ".ls", ".lt", ".lu", ".lv", ".ly", ".ma", ".mc", ".md", ".me", ".mh", ".mk", ".ml", ".mn", ".mo", ".mp", ".mq", ".mr", ".ms", ".mt", ".mu", ".mv", ".mw", ".mx", ".my", ".mz", ".na", ".nc", ".ne", ".nf", ".ng", ".ni", ".nl", ".no", ".np", ".nr", ".nu", ".nz", ".om", ".pa", ".pe", ".pf", ".pg", ".ph", ".pk", ".pl", ".pm", ".pn", ".pr", ".ps", ".pt", ".pw", ".py", ".qa", ".re", ".ro", ".rs", ".ru", ".rw", ".sa", ".sb", ".sc", ".sd", ".se", ".sg", ".sh", ".si", ".sk", ".sl", ".sm", ".sn", ".sp", ".sr", ".ss", ".st", ".sv", ".su", ".sx", ".sy", ".sz", ".tc", ".td", ".tf", ".tg", ".th", ".tj", ".tk", ".tl", ".tm", ".tn", ".to", ".tr", ".tt", ".tv", ".tw", ".tz", ".ua", ".ug", ".uk", ".us", ".uy", ".uz", ".va", ".vc", ".ve", ".vg", ".vi", ".vn", ".vu", ".wf", ".ws", ".ye", ".za", ".zm", ".zw", ".name", ".pro", ".aero", ".asia", ".cat", ".coop", ".jobs", ".museum", ".tel", ".travel");
    foreach ($arr as &$findme) {
           $value = strpos($mystring, $findme);
           if ($value === false) {
           } else {
               $this->set_error();
           }
    }
```

Check the tick box that says 'Set errors using field API'

In the last text box you add your custom error message. E.g.

```
Please remove all links/URLs for example: 'www', '.co.uk'& '.com'. Please check that you have a space after each full stop.
```

I hope that this helps somebody else.